# Why is there space between the li's in my nav bar?

Tags: css

See this CodePen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/slKIv?editors=110.

The `<li>`s don't have any padding or margins. And the `<a>`s only have padding. Why is there space between them?

Comment: Dublicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 1):

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbFqc)

every `inline` will give extra space of at-least `2-3px` at the right side so you need to give `float:left` and for parent display `inline-block`